# Left-aligned, rather than centered list of symbols

Tags: horizontal-alignment, symbols

By default, my list of symbols is centered:

[image]

How do I make it left-aligned, just like my above list of figures? Here is what I use in the preambule:

```
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Cumulative distribution function attached to the point process}]{F(x)}{\ensuremath{F(x)}}  
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Same as $F(x/s)$}]{F_s(x)}{\ensuremath{F_s(x)}}  
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Density attached to $F$}]{f(x)}{\ensuremath{f(x)}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Density attached to $f_s$}]{f_s(x)}{\ensuremath{f_s(x)}}
```

And in the main document:

```
\listoffigures
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]  % list of symbols
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `long` style is based on `longtable`, you automatically end up with a horizontally centered list. To nevertheless left align it, you can define your own custom style based on the original definition of the `long` style:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%     %<-------------- added [l] and @{} here
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space
     ##3\tabularnewline
  }%
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & \tabularnewline}%
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the option style=super, rather than style=long, also fixes the issue.

Comment: @VincentGranville: Using the `super` style will result in a slightly different horizontal position of the symbols with respect to the title, though.

Comment: I'll have to try them both. For now, my main issue is to get a glossary entry that contains  Greek or some other math symbols, say \glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Intensity}]{$lambda}{\ensuremath{$lambda}}  (this does not work), then getting two glossaries (list of symbols + actual glossary). Hopefully, I'll figure that out on my own, otherwise I'll ask another question.